# Excel: Create lookup based on list of criteria

Tags: excel, mapping, lookup

I have a little bit of an Excel problem and would be happy about any suggestions.

**Long version:** I have a dataset with raw data representing journal entries. The structure of this dataset can be seen here:

[image]

Now, what I want to achieve is to assign each row/each journal entry to a cost category (marketing, personnel, IT, depreciation, …) based on the values in the account number, type, and cost center rows, and, in a second step, break down the categories once more, eg. for labour costs, distinguish between direct and indirect labour costs.

The way my company does this right now is using an Excel sheet with several macros where the criteria are hardcoded in the VBA code to loop through the whole list, check if a row matches the criteria for a certain cost category, and if it does, copy the row to a new sheet (having one new sheet for each category), then using a second macro to break down the categories, assigning values to the “description”-column which is empty initially based on another set of criteria. Then, pivot tables are used on each of the new sub-datasets to calculate sums for each sub-category. These sums are finally used as input data for a management report (as seen in the image above) which is the ultimate goal of this whole ordeal.

Now, not only does this seem overly complicated to me and running the macros and manually adjusting the input ranges for the pivot tables takes forever, but also the criteria for allocating the costs can change quite often, and opening the VBA editor and changing the code is not really user-friendly.The initial idea was to maybe include some helper columns (one for each cost category) and somehow create an indicator variable being one of the entry falls in the respective category, and zero otherwise, and then use these columns for further calculations (e.g. for Sumifs and such).

The problem is that a) combinations of account number and type are not unique, so that one account number can go along with various types, and one type can go along with various account numbers, so the criteria can be something like C6 = 544300 OR 544700 AND D6<>110246, etc. And b) criteria can change, meaning sometimes a new account number or type is added that also has to be assigned to an already existing category such as labor costs, which would make it necessary to include that criterion in all the formulas for that particular cost category. So, is it possible to somehow create a criteria table for each category that serves as input for some sort of IF/SUMIF or lookup function?

**Short version:** I have a data set (can range from 5000 to up to 100000 rows, 8 columns) where I want to perform a lookup, but based on various criteria. And, in addition to that, it would be nice if the criteria could somehow be drawn from a separate list so that they can be modified fairly easily without having to change the formula itself. Is there a way to do so? Or do you think using the advanced filter might be the most suitable option?

Comment: There's a lot of text here but it's impossible to answer in much detail without know exactly how it works right now.  Can you replace hard-coded values in the VBA with some kind of lookup table?  Yes, and that would likely be a worthwhile improvement.  Exactly how would you do that?  That's difficult to say without seeing the existing setup, and without knowing what your level of VBA knowledge is.

Comment: Alright, thanks for reading through that whole wall of text and answering. Guess VBA it is the way to go then. My knowledge in that area is still quite limited, but the task at hand does not necessarily have to be improved immediately, so I'll try to learn some more VBA whenever I encounter something I can't solve. I looked into the whole thing a bit more today, and tried setting up lists with criteria for each category, creating a named range for each list, and then reference that in the VBA code. Not really sure if that works out in the end with all the other steps, but it's a start